# How can a demon mitigate the danger of Compromise when changing to demon form?

Tags: chronicles-of-darkness-2e, demon-the-descent

On p.43 of the *Demon: The Descent* manual we find:

> Some demons feel much more comfortable in their demonic form, to the point that they try to arrange their lives so that they can spend some time that way every day. These demons sometimes band together to create safe spaces where they can assume their demonic forms and "let their hair down" without worrying about curious humans or the God-Machine's agents.

Given that full transformation results in a Compromise roll at -3 dice (p.113), how can a demon change fully every day without Compromise?  Are there ways that PCs can mitigate this roll?

Answer (score 2):

**Yes, there are.**

According to the rules on Compromises in the Demon: the Descent corebook, it is possible to gain positive modifiers on a Compromise roll: the two that are listed are if all witnesses are drunk or high (a +1 modifier to the roll), or having a high Cover rating (a +1 bonus for having a Cover of 6-7, or a +2 bonus for having a Cover of 8-10). It's mentioned that GMs can grant other circumstance bonuses to the roll, but these are the only ones listed.

Additionally, they can further mitigate this by simply restoring any lost points of Cover through Pacts; a Pact with a Medial Cover aspect grants two Cover Experiences, which is sufficient to restore a lost dot of Cover.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the modifiers for the Compromise roll listed on p.113-4 you can use the Interference Mundane Embed (p.144) either in Gear or an Interlock.

On a story level, if finding/building a place where you can "let your hair down" is important to the demon, this is likely part of their search for Hell.

In that context the ST and player could build it into the five Compromise questions and/or the Cypher. The ST could perhaps develop custom Conditions which could modify the Compromise roll if the demon prepares appropriately. Or  make custom Merits/Embeds/Exploits for various steps along the path to Hell.